# Sigil of Wisdom, and Sigil of Power

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just got the Quest to Collect 10 Sigils of Power and 10 Sigils of Wisdom from the Black Prince. Wondering if I can do LFR to get these items or if I need to do normal version of the raids to get them.

**UPDATE: 11/5/2012 (Patch 5.0)**

I have been doing Mogu'shan Vaults on LFR, and it seems that Mogu'shan Vaults only drops Sigils of Power. My guess is that the other raids will drop drop the Sigils of Wisdom. I will know more on Tuesday when Heart of Fear Part 1 is open for LFR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both the Sigils of Power and Wisdom are obtainable from LFR, as is the follow-up quest item and all of the Sha-Touched Weaponry that tie into the Legendary quest. This is by design, as Blizzard feels that all people who raid (at the LFR level or better) should be able to see the quest line, as well as increasing the "value" of said quest lines (as everyone can do them, not one specific class a la Fangs of the Father).

Note that when they do drop, all raiders on that step of the quest get the Sigil - there is no competition for it, as in past legendaries. This is true on all raiding difficulties, as well.

Comment: To add onto this answer. Everyone in the group gets one Sigil per boss. So there is no fighting over them. (maybe not per boss, but the ones that drop them)

Comment: @leety Thanks, knew I forgot something. I've edited that in accordingly. :)

Comment: Thank You. Could not for the life of me figure out if i could get them from LFR or not

Comment: Your last sentence is inaccurate. Sigils in LFR work just like loot. Every eligible person has an individual chance to receive one. It does not drop for the entire group like it does in normal and heroic mode.